# Der Erwerb von Lesekompetenz/Gebrauch der Artikel

Tags: article

> Der Erwerb von Lesekompetenz durchzieht die ganze Schullfaufbahn, wobei die literarische Kompetenz eine besondere, die Entwicklung junger Menschen fördernde Stellung einnimmt.

oder

> Der Erwerb **der** Lesekompetenz durchzieht die ganze Schullfaufbahn, wobei die literarische Kompetenz eine besondere, die Entwicklung junger Menschen fördernde Stellung einnimmt.

Ich glaube, der Artikel soll gebraucht werden, weil es nur eine Lesekompetenz gibt. Das ist ja nur eine Fähigkeit.

Um die Frage zu präzisieren: Ich frage, warum in diesem Satz kein bestimmter Artikel eingesetzt wurde.

Comment: Entweder _von_ oder _der_, aber nicht beides zusammen.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Ist das eine Antwort oder ein Kommentar?

Comment: @user Offensichtlich ein Kommentar ;-)

Comment: Nun ja, Du pickst die Kirsche vom Kuchen, ohne sie zu essen, und überlässt den anderen die schnöde Arbeit das auszuarbeiten. Das finde, ich ist für andere sehr unbefriedigend.

Comment: Dieses Kommentar ergibt leider keinen Sinn. Man kann "von der" benutzen, um den Genitiv zu ersetzen. Ich bräuchte eine tüchtige Erklärung.

Comment: @Taman _von der_ kann schon immer den Genitiv ersetzen, das fällt aber in eine komplett andere Stilebene, und passt einfach nicht mit einem so akademischen Satz zusammen. (Je umgangssprachlicher, desto weniger Genitiv.)

Comment: Sie haben sich widersprochen.

Comment: @Taman ein kleiner Tippfehler versteckt sich in Schull**f**aufbahn (statt Schullaufbahn)

Comment: "Erwerb von der Lesekompetenz" ist nicht einfach umgangssprachlich, sondern allenfalls Mundart. Außerdem ist da auch ein Widerspruch zwischen "es gibt nur eine Lesekompetenz" und "wobei die literarische eine besondere".

Comment: @Taman Woher stammt das erste Beispiel?

Comment: @Nico Aus einem Lehrbuch für das Goethe-Zertifikat C2.

Answer (score 3):

Aus meiner Sicht sind sowohl der unbestimmte als auch der bestimmte Artikel möglich, allerdings mit einem kleinen Unterschied.

"Der Erwerb **der** ... " bedeutet meiner Ansicht nach, dass die Kompetenz als etwas betrachtet wird, dass entweder vollständig oder gar nicht erworben wird.

"Der Erwerb **von** ... " ist meines Erachtens vielleicht etwas realistischer, da er impliziert, das Kompetenz auch bis zu einem gewissen Grad erworben werden kann. Viele Menschen können zwar prinzipiell lesen, scheitern aber daran schnell oder laut zu lesen. Diese Menschen sind nicht inkompetent, könnten aber mit Übung wahrscheinlich noch kompetenter werden.

Answer (score 0):

Das sind eigentlich zwei Fragen, miteinander gemischt.  Erstens: ja, *von der* kann immer den Genitiv ersetzen, aber nur in einer komplett anderen Stilebene.  Und diese passt einfach nicht mit einem so akademischen Satz zusammen.  (Je formeller und schriftlicher, desto eher Genitiv.)  Das ist eine Frage der pragmatischen Akzeptabilität, nicht so sehr der Grammatikalität.

Was man dagegen schon sagen kann, mit gleicher Bedeutung, ist *der Erwerb der Lesekompetenz*.  *Lesekompetenz* ist grundsätzlich ein Abstraktum.  Das Konzept ist intrinsisch weder zählbar noch unzählbar, kann aber kognitiv in beiden Formen konstruiert werden.  *Der Erwerb von Lesekompetenz* bildet sie eher als unbestimmtes Ganzes ab, wie *der Erwerb von Bier*.  *Der Erwerb der Lesekompetenz* dagegen bedeutet sie eher eine zählbare, bestimmte Einheit, wie *der Erwerb der Banane*.

Letzteres würde im gegebenen Satz sogar angemessener sein, da die Lesekompetenz als eine bestimmte Kompetenz von der literarischen abgegrenzt wird.

Comment: "Lesekompetenz" ist definitiv unzählbar vs. Kompetenzen. Es gibt keine verschiedenen Sorten von "Lesekompetenzen", wohingegen es verschiedene Sorten von Kompetenzen gibt.

Comment: Ich bin mit dem Thema nicht vertraut, aber wenn wir mal, sagen wir, "literarische Lesekomptenz und kreative Lesekomptetenz" erfinden, dann kategorisieren wir zwei Lesekompetenzen. Konzepte sind ja nicht an und für sich (un)zählbar, sondern nur prototypischerweise.

Comment: Kann man natürlich auch so konstruieren, aber "Lesekompetenz" bezieht sich auf diegesamte  Fähigkeit, Texte zu erfassen -egal welcher Art. Es ist schwer vorstellbar, dass jemand eine Geschichte, aber nicht einen Bericht versteht. Deine Hypothese ist nicht unplausibel, aber bisher wurde das noch nie so heruntergebrochen in der sprachlichen Verwendung.

Comment: Ach so, ja. Inhaltlich habe ich überhaupt nicht darüber nachgedacht und mich nur auf die Verwendung bezogen, und es hört sich einfach nicht falsch an (Geisteswissenschaftler haben ja oft so eine Tendenz zur elaborierten Pluralisierung).

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, ob du mit Lakoffs Prototypentheorie vertraut bist, aber deine Bemerkung wäre dort gut aufgehoben. Heißt, wenn Sprecher ein Bedürfnis nach detaillierterer Kategorisierung eines Begriffs durch Wörter haben, setzten sich solche Wörter irgendwann mal durch.

Comment: Prototypensemantik habe ich beim Antworten eh im Hinterkopf gehabt. Aber meinen wir jetzt das gleiche? Mein Ansatz wäre: "Lesekomptetenz" ist prototypisch unzählbar, kann aber bei Bedarf in einen Sortenplural gesetzt werden.

Comment: Ja, wenn man es für nötig erhielte, diese Differenzierung von Kompetenzen sprachlich zu kodieren. Bisher ist das noch nicht der Fall. Heißt Sprecher haben es bis jetzt noch keinen Bedarf empfunden zu unterscheiden, z.B. zwischen: "er hat eine Geschichten-Lesekompetenz", aber keine "Bericht-Lesekompetenz"